# JMeter-WebDriver Sampler integration with maven using Jmeter-maven plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

Just wanted to know, whether jmeter-maven plugin supports jmeter webdriver integration or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works but you should ensure you use last version of [jmeter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin).

Read this detailed [blog](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/) on how to proceed.

A working pom.xml should be:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>training-project</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests2</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>results</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration> 
                        <jmeterExtensions>
                            <artifacts>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:2.3</artifacts>
                        </jmeterExtensions>
                        <excludedArtifacts>
                            <exclusion>commons-pool2:commons-pool2</exclusion>
                            <exclusion>commons-math3:commons-math3</exclusion>
                            <exclusion>com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools</exclusion>
                            <exclusion>com.sun.jmx:jmxri</exclusion>
                        </excludedArtifacts>
                        <ignoreResultFailures>false</ignoreResultFailures>
                        <downloadOptionalDependencies>false</downloadOptionalDependencies>
                        <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does.

Just in case here is a minimal *pom.xml* file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-webdriver:1.4.0</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also check out following material:

- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: yeah.. i tried this and now am getting:

cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
[INFO] cause-message       : org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException